# Running gulp as a service

Tags: nginx, jenkins, gulp

We have a project where the developers (from what I understand) use gulp to run a website locally using Vagrant. They want to deploy this website on an AWS instance.

We are trying to implement the commands using Jenkins. The website stays up while `gulp serve-dev` is running, but then Jenkins times out and Nginx returns a 502 error. Of course we can prevent Jenkins from timing out but then the job would need to keep running.

Is there away to run this command as a service? any other way we can go about this ?

Answer (score 0):

You want to run gulp in the backgroud without stoppping when you close terminal or log out from the server.

Try using `nohup`(short for `no hangup`) which runs command with `hangup` ignored  so that your command continue running even if you logout from the server

try running it using `nohup gulp serve-dev &`

`&` put command in background mode so that you can continue using the current shell screen.

Cheers!

Comment: Instead of nohup... Cant we run gulp as service?? I want this under chkconfig. Is that possible??